# Split value into two with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a text file that looks like this and I'm splitting at each '|'.
In between the 3rd '|' is two words that I need to split into two separate columns. Having trouble doing the split.

```
 Nbr| Address| Name   |Phone|City|State|Zip 
455 |gsgdgsg |fir last|434  |jk  |jh   |0393
```

I have something like this that is doing the split and writing the output to a list. Currently I can do the split and select the first part fine but when i do the split and select the second part I get index out of bounds of array error.

```
var Names = File
            .ReadAllLines(path)
            .Select(a => a.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.None))
            .Select(a => new {
                phoneNbr = a[0].Trim(),
                Name = a[2].Trim().Split(' ')[0],
                Name2 = a[2].Trim().Split(' ')[1], //gives me error I think becuase it already split it
                addr = a[1].Trim()
            })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Does an inner value ever have `|`? Are the field lengths fixed?

Comment: No these '|' only separate the fields. ANd the lengths are not fixed values thats why I have to split at the whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not have two words in column three with index 2 with some record. You need to enusure you get two elements after split before using second element.

*Change*

```
Name2 = a[2].Trim().Split(' ')[1]
```

*To*

```
Name2 = a[2].Trim().Split(' ').Length > 1 ? a[2].Trim().Split(' ')[1] : ""
```

Comment: Oh man I forgot all about that the file heading doesn't have a space. but your code handles it if it doesn't thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rolling your own structured text file parser, use a library.

The `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace contains the [`TextFileParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class or you can use a third party library like the popular [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Such libraries take care of many subtle issues that can crop up when dealing with parsing such files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to split a[2].

```
Regex.Split(a[2].Trim(), @"\W+")[0];
Regex.Split(a[2].Trim(), @"\W+")[1];
```

Regex Split examples
http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split

Answer (score 0):

Try following syntax

```
var Names = (from s in File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(a => a.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.None))
        let namestr=s[2].Trim().Split(' ')
        select new {
            phoneNbr = s[0].Trim(),
            Name = namestr.Length >=1 ? namestr[0] :"",
            Name2 = namestr.Length >=2 ? namestr[1] :"", 
            addr = s[1].Trim()
        }).ToList();
```

It splits name only once and also check for null values.